# How to connect to local mongodb from docker container of flask application

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have a flask application which is running as docker container. Flask application uses local mongodb. This docker container is not able to connect to local mongodb.

I have tried following option :

- set `--network="host"` in `docker run ...` command
- set `MONGO_URI = "mongodb://host-ip-address:27017/model-service-sample"`,
- set `MONGO_URI = "mongodb://container-gateway-ip-address:27017/model-service-sample"`

None of the above options worked.

Can anyone please suggest a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using MacOS?

Comment: did you expose port for mongo when `docker run -p xxxx:27017 mongoimage` ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan , yes I am using macOS and my mongodb is not running as docker container, my flask application which is running as a docker container needs to access local mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MacOS you should use:

`host.docker.internal` or `gateway.docker.internal`

for connecting from a container to a service on the host.

refer : https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#/known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds

Comment: I read about this but couldn't quite understand what does ```host.docker.internal``` mean. Do I need to write this in my ```Dockerfile```?

Comment: no, change `MONGO_URI = "mongodb://container-gateway-ip-address:27017/model-service-sample"` to `MONGO_URI = "mongodb://gateway.docker.internal:27017/model-service-sample"`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Thanks, man! You saved me!